# Get correct mouseover interaction in a ThreeJS VueJS app changing the window

Tags: vue.js, three.js, responsive

I'm quite proud of what I've done: I have a menu which comprises 4 shapes. When you hover a shape, it's chaging color, growing and pushing the other shapes on top, while the rotation gets slower.

I read the ThreeJS docs and follow the advices of StackOverflow members.

I'm struggling with mouse interactions and window resizing: when I first open the browser, the mouseover doesn't seem to be called exactly when the mouse is over.
And when I resize the window, it's clearly messed up.
If anybody has a clue on what I'm doing wrong, thanks in advance :)

Here is my component:

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <div @click="onClick" @mousemove="onMouseMove" id="menu3D" style="background-color: transparent; position: fixed; left: 20px; width:15%; height:100%;"></div>
    <v-row class="text-center">

      <v-col
        class="mb-5"
        cols="12"
      >
        <h2 class="headline font-weight-bold mb-3">
          Accueil
        </h2>

        <v-row justify="center">

          <p>
            THIS IS ONLY A TEST
          </p>
        </v-row>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>

  import * as Three from 'three'

  export default {
    name: 'Home',
    mounted() {
      this.init();
    },
    methods: {
      init: function() {
       this.createScene();
       this.createCamera();
       this.userData.formes.forEach(x=>this.createShape(x))
       this.addSpotlight(16777215/*'#fdffab'*/);
       this.addAmbientLight();
       this.animate();
       window.addEventListener('resize', this.onResize())
      },
      onResize: function() {
       let container = document.getElementById('menu3D');
       this.renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);
       this.camera.aspect = container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight;
       this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      },
      createScene: function() {

       this.renderer = new Three.WebGLRenderer({
         antialias: true,
         alpha: true
       });
       let container = document.getElementById('menu3D');
       this.renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);
       this.renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
       this.renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff,0);
       container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
      },

      createCamera: function() {
        //let container = document.getElementById('container');
       this.camera = new Three.PerspectiveCamera(50, 1.686275 /*container.clientWidth/container.clientHeight*/, 0.01, 1000);
       this.camera.position.set(0, 5, 20);
       this.camera.zoom = 1;
      },

      createShape: function(shape) {

       let material = new Three.MeshStandardMaterial({
        "color": '#0000ff'/*16777215*/,
        "roughness": 1,
        "metalness": 0.5,
        "emissive": 0,
        "depthFunc": 3,
        "depthTest": true,
        "depthWrite": true,
        "stencilWrite": false,
        "stencilWriteMask": 255,
        "stencilFunc": 519,
        "stencilRef": 0,
        "stencilFuncMask": 255,
        "stencilFail": 7680,
        "stencilZFail": 7680,
        "stencilZPass": 7680
       })
       switch (shape.nom) {
         case "Box": {
           this.geometry = new Three.BoxBufferGeometry(1.8,1.8,1.8)
           break;
         }
         case "Sphere": {
           this.geometry = new Three.SphereBufferGeometry(1,8,6,0,6.283185,0, 3.141593)
           break;
         }
         case "Dodecahedron": {
           this.geometry = new Three.DodecahedronBufferGeometry(1.2,0)
           break;
         }
         case "Icosahedron": {
           this.geometry = new Three.IcosahedronBufferGeometry(1.5,0)
           break;
         }
       }
       this.mesh = new Three.Mesh(this.geometry, material)
       this.mesh.name = shape.nom
       this.mesh.userData = shape.userData
       this.mesh.receiveShadow = true
       this.mesh.castShadow = true
       this.mesh.position.set(0, shape.userData.position.y, 0)
       this.scene.add(this.mesh)
      },

      addSpotlight: function(color) {
       const light = new Three.SpotLight(color, 2, 1000)
       light.position.set(0, 0, 30)
       this.scene.add(light)
      },

      addAmbientLight: function() {
       const light = new Three.AmbientLight('#fff', 0.5)
       this.scene.add(light)
      },

      verifForme: function(e) {
        let t = this
        let elt = t.scene.getObjectByName(e);
            t.intersects = t.raycaster.intersectObject(elt);
            if (t.intersects.length !== 0) {
                // if it's not in the array, we put it at the beginning
                if (t.userData.souris.indexOf(e)<0) {
                    t.userData.souris.unshift(e);
                    console.log(t.userData.souris[0] + " survolé!");
                }
                if (t.userData.souris[0] == e) {
                    let obj = t.intersects[0].object;
                    obj.material.color.set('#'+elt.userData.couleurs[1]);
                    obj.scale.set(obj.scale.x<1.4?obj.scale.x+t.VITESSE_ZOOM:obj.scale.x,obj.scale.y<1.4?obj.scale.y+t.VITESSE_ZOOM:obj.scale.y,obj.scale.z<1.4?obj.scale.z+t.VITESSE_ZOOM:obj.scale.z);
                    obj.rotation.y += t.VITESSE_ROTATION/t.RALENTISSEMENT
                    t.replacer(obj,obj.userData.position.y+obj.userData.decalage)

                }
                else {
                    t.retrecir(e,elt);
                }
        }
            else {
                if (t.userData.souris.indexOf(e)>=0) {
                    t.userData.souris = t.userData.souris.filter(forme => forme != e);
                }
                t.retrecir(e,elt);
            }
      },

      onClick: function ( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
            if (this.userData.souris.length >0 ) { console.log(this.userData.souris[0] + " clicked!"); }
        else {
          console.log("click outside!")
        }
        },

      onMouseMove: function(event){
        let container = document.getElementById('menu3D');
        this.mouse.x = ( event.clientX / container.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
        this.mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / container.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1;
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(this.mouse))
      },

      replacer: function(e,py) {
            // next line to prevent shaking
            if (Math.abs(e.position.y - py) < 0.05) { return true }
            let rhesus = 10*this.VITESSE_ZOOM
        if (this.userData.souris[0] != e.name) { rhesus *= 3 }
        //console.log(e.name+': '+this.userData.souris[0]+' - '+rhesus)
            if (e.position.y > py) { rhesus = -1 }
            e.position.set(0,Math.trunc(10*e.position.y+rhesus)/10,0)
        },

      retrecir: function (n,e) {
            // checking if the clicked element is on top
            let dec = 0
        let elt = this
            if ((elt.userData.souris.length > 0) && (elt.userData.formes.map(x=>x.nom).indexOf(n)<elt.userData.formes.map(x=>x.nom).indexOf(elt.userData.souris[0]))) {
                dec = Math.trunc(10*e.parent.getObjectByName(elt.userData.souris[0]).userData.decalage*2.1)/10;
            }
            e.material.color.set('#'+e.userData.couleurs[0]);
            e.rotation.y += elt.VITESSE_ROTATION
            e.scale.set(e.scale.x>1?e.scale.x-elt.VITESSE_ZOOM:e.scale.x,e.scale.y>1?e.scale.y-elt.VITESSE_ZOOM:e.scale.y,e.scale.z>1?e.scale.z-elt.VITESSE_ZOOM:e.scale.z);
            let newY = e.userData.position.y+dec
            if (e.position.y != newY) {
                elt.replacer(e,newY)
            }
        },

      animate: function() {
         let elt = this
         requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
         this.raycaster.setFromCamera(this.mouse, this.camera);
         this.userData.formes.map(x=>x.nom).forEach(x=>elt.verifForme(x))
         if (this.userData.souris.length >0 ) { document.body.style.cursor = "pointer"; }
         else { document.body.style.cursor = "default"; }
         this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
         this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
      }
    },
    data: () => ({
      scene: new Three.Scene(),
      camera: null,
      renderer: Three.WebGLRenderer,
      mesh: new Three.Mesh,
      factor:0,
      mouse : new Three.Vector2(1, 1),
      raycaster : new Three.Raycaster(),
      intersects : [],
      VITESSE_ROTATION: 0.05,
      VITESSE_ZOOM: 0.1,
      RALENTISSEMENT: 3,
      userData: {
        "souris": [],
        "formes": [
          {
            "nom": "Box",
            "userData": {
              "position": {
                "x": 0,
                "y": 7.8,
                "z": 0
              },
              "couleurs": [
                "aaaaaa",
                "095256"
              ],
              "decalage": 0.5
            }
          },
          {
            "nom": "Icosahedron",
            "userData": {
              "position": {
                "x": 0,
                "y": 5.5,
                "z": 0
              },
              "couleurs": [
                "aaaaaa",
                "087F8C"
              ],
              "decalage": 0.5
            }
          },
          {
            "nom": "Dodecahedron",
            "userData": {
              "position": {
                "x": 0,
                "y": 3.1,
                "z": 0
              },
              "couleurs": [
                "aaaaaa",
                "5AAA95"
              ],
              "decalage": 0.4
            }
          },
          {
            "nom": "Sphere",
            "userData": {
              "position": {
                "x": 0,
                "y": 1,
                "z": 0
              },
              "couleurs": [
                "aaaaaa",
                "86A873"
              ],
              "decalage": 0.2
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }),
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is what you really want? `this.mouse.x = ( event.clientX / container.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;`

Comment: What I really want is to have the 3D change size when I change the window size and the hover effect to be precise even when I resize the window. I found this formula on a tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I investigated the problem using the code you provided and fixed it locally so I'm hoping it also works for you.  The issues are the following:

1. A tiny hard to find typo in the attachment of the resize event: instead of `window.addEventListener('resize', this.onResize())` you need to use `window.addEventListener('resize', this.onResize);` removing the `()` because you don't want to call the function at the time of the attachment, you want it called each time the event is triggered.
2. Due to the first issue, as the resize function wasn't getting called when you expected, I guess this is what led you to use a hard-coded value (1.686275) in the camera instantiation instead of the recommended formula `container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight` so you need to change that back to

```js
createCamera: function () {
    let container = document.getElementById('menu3D');
    this.camera = new Three.PerspectiveCamera(50, container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight, 0.01, 1000);
    ...
```

3. Also as the 3D container `div` is not in the root level of the HTML `body` due to VueJS requirements, in `onMouseMove()` you need to consume the offset coordinates instead of the client ones as follows:

```js
onMouseMove: function (event) {
  let container = document.getElementById('menu3D');
  this.mouse.x = (event.offsetX / container.clientWidth) * 2 - 1;
  this.mouse.y = - (event.offsetY / container.clientHeight) * 2 + 1;
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, everything works like a charm. I understood my mistakes. There goes your bounty, you deserve it!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the problem originates from the creation of your camera:

`this.camera = new Three.PerspectiveCamera(50, 1.686275 /*container.clientWidth/container.clientHeight*/, 0.01, 1000);`

Why are you using the magical aspect number `1.686275` instead of the actual `width/height` ratio like you do on resize? This is giving you a different behavior before and after resizing.

This is my best guess at first glance, although I presume there are other instances of hard coded “magic numbers” in your app that need to be re-calculated based on the screen’s width and height. I couldn't possibly read through the 300 lines of code you posted. You should consider isolating the problem to create a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add it to your question via [a code snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) so we can see your code in action.